# Distribution of sum of squares of two normal random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X1$ and $X2$ be independent random variables, each following a normal density with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Find the distribution of

$R = \sqrt{(X1^2 + X2^2)}$?

Hint: Let X1 = R cos θ and X2 = R sin θ. Obtain the joint pdf of R and θ, then integrate out θ.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank for letting me know about mathjax notation.

Answer (score 0):

The joint density of $(X_1,x_2)$ is the following

$$f_{X_1X_2}(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{x_1+x_2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

now simply passing in polar coordinates you get

$$f_{R\Theta}(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\times \frac{r}{\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}}=f_{\Theta}(\theta)\times f_R(r)$$

Where

$f_{\Theta}$ is the angle's distribution, uniform in $[0;2\pi]$

$ f_R(r)$ is the "radius distribution", as requested, a [Rayleigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution)

thus not any integration is needed to answer